# Записать каждый список в списке списков в отдельный txt файл

Tags: python, list, txt

Есть список списков:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Как списать каждый элемент списка в отдельный txt файл, чтобы получить следующий результат:

```
[1,2,3] - text-1.txt
[4,5,6] - text-2.txt
[7,8,9] - text-3.txt
```

я пробовала следующий подход:

```
def text (res,k): 
    for element in res: 
        with open(f'text-{k}.txt','w') as f: 
            f.write(json.dumps(element)) 
    return
```

Comment: что вы пробовали? это простой цикл

Comment: def text (res,k): for element in res: with open(f'text-{k}.txt','w') as f: f.write(json.dumps(element)) return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что аргумент `k` не меняется в цикле, и Вы перезаписываете один и тот же файл. Воспользуйтесь функцией [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), чтобы пронумеровать каждый элемент Вашей последовательности.

***Пример:***

```py
import json


def text(res): 
    for k, element in enumerate(res, 1): 
        with open(f'text-{k}.txt', 'w') as f: 
            f.write(json.dumps(element)) 


res = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
text(res)
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо что пояснили ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Пишем цикл и в нем запускаем функцию, которая записывает файлы

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
PATH = '../путь/к/папке/'
def write2TxtFile(text, file_name):
    f = open(   f'{PATH}{file_name}.txt'  , 'w')
    f.write(json.dumps(text))
    f.close()

for idx, item in enumerate(list):
    write2TxtFile(item, f'text-{idx}')
```

Comment: функцию надо определять до ее использования

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]